wxmaxima wxdraw , wxdraw2d, wxdraw3d. How to change output to a *.png file instead of terminal computer screen
I have successfully changed the output from default terminal screen to a *.png by for example.
[load(implicit_plot),
 gnuplot_out_file[png,"gnu.png"],   
 implicit_plot(x^2+y^2-1,[x,-1,1],[y,-1,1], [gnuplot_term, png], [gnuplot_term, "png size 334,334"]  )]

But since plot cannot fill a figure i need to do it in wxdraw,wxdraw2d,wxdraw3d but have not had success. I tried
(wxdraw3d (enhanced3d = true,explicit(exp(x^2-y^2), x,-2,2,y,-2,2)),wxdraw_file(terminal="draw.png" ))

But it ignored the terminal request. Also
xdraw_file(terminal="draw.png",dimensions=[5,5]);

Did nothing either and i did not get any error output on either. Also the following got no error but did nothing to change color.
set_draw_defaults(color=grey20);

Why is it not working. What can i do. Note I can't use just plain draw because it fails on everything.

for equiv what can do in wxdraw2d and ...3d just replace wxdraw2d or 3d by
gr2d or gr3d and preface it by wxdraw(terminal='png,"file_name=",..
such as in example:    wxdraw(terminal='png,file_name="dotted", gr2d(fill_color=gray84,ellipse(0,0,1,1,0,360), fill_color=grey77,color=gray20,line_width=2,
ellipse(0,0,1,.23,180,180), line_type=dashes, ellipse(0,0,1,.23,0,180),  proportional_axes='xy))
and found the file dotted.png in my ...\maxima-current directory and which is the same image that also appears on the screen.
